# Fetching data from a service using Data Table(TeraData Covalent)

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-material, teradata-covalent

I am trying to fetch data from a service and show them in a datatable using [Covalent](https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/components/data-table) , the only issue I seem not to figure out how to go about it. Initially Was using twitter bootstrap with datable and it was working fine. I was chug to material design 2 using covalent, this is the only part am stuck.

Here is my component

```
getSpReceiptsList(){
  //console.log(this.webApiPathService.getWebApiPath('get-sp-receipts').path);
  this.getReceiptService.getReceipts( this.webApiPathService.getWebApiPath('get-sp-receipts').path, this.token)
  .subscribe(response => {
      if(response){
          this.spReceiptsList = this.getReceiptService.getReceiptsList();
          this.spReceiptsList.forEach((object)=>{
              let paymentDate = new Date(object.paymentDate);
              let year = paymentDate.getFullYear();
              let month = paymentDate.getMonth()+1;
              let dt = paymentDate.getDate();    
              let hours = paymentDate.getHours();
              let minutes = paymentDate.getMinutes();
              let seconds = paymentDate.getSeconds();
              object.paymentDate = dt+'-' + month + '-'+year+' '+hours+':' + minutes + ':'+seconds;
          });

      }else{
          this.snackBar.open('No receipts exist', '', {
                  duration: 2000,
          });
      }
  }, 
  errMsg => {
      this.snackBar.open(errMsg, '', {
          duration: 2000,
      });
      console.log(errMsg);
  });
}

  //Covalent
  data: any[] = [
    { approve: 'True', serviceName: 'Hotel', userName: 'gbrigens', amount: 1000, paymentDate: '12/08/2017' },
  ];
  columns: ITdDataTableColumn[] = [
    { name: 'approve', label: 'APPROVE', tooltip: 'Approve' },
    { name: 'serviceName', label: 'SERVICE NAME' },
    { name: 'userName', label: 'USER NAME' },
    { name: 'amount', label: 'AMOUNT' },
    { name: 'paymentDate', label: 'PAYMENT DATE' }
  ];

  filteredData: any[] = this.data;
  filteredTotal: number = this.data.length;

  searchTerm: string = '';
  fromRow: number = 1;
  currentPage: number = 1;
  pageSize: number = 5;
  sortBy: string = 'approve';
  selectedRows: any[] = [];
  sortOrder: TdDataTableSortingOrder = TdDataTableSortingOrder.Descending;

  sort(sortEvent: ITdDataTableSortChangeEvent): void {
    this.sortBy = sortEvent.name;
    this.sortOrder = sortEvent.order;
    this.filter();
  }

  search(searchTerm: string): void {
    this.searchTerm = searchTerm;
    this.filter();
  }

  page(pagingEvent: IPageChangeEvent): void {
    this.fromRow = pagingEvent.fromRow;
    this.currentPage = pagingEvent.page;
    this.pageSize = pagingEvent.pageSize;
    this.filter();
  }

  filter(): void {
    let newData: any[] = this.data;
    let excludedColumns: string[] = this.columns
    .filter((column: ITdDataTableColumn) => {
      return ((column.filter === undefined && column.hidden === true) ||
              (column.filter !== undefined && column.filter === false));
    }).map((column: ITdDataTableColumn) => {
      return column.name;
    });
    newData = this._dataTableService.filterData(newData, this.searchTerm, true, excludedColumns);
    this.filteredTotal = newData.length;
    newData = this._dataTableService.sortData(newData, this.sortBy, this.sortOrder);
    newData = this._dataTableService.pageData(newData, this.fromRow, this.currentPage * this.pageSize);
    this.filteredData = newData;
  }
```

Template to show the table

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="start center" class="pad-left-sm pad-right-sm">
  <span *ngIf="!searchBox.searchVisible" class="push-left-sm">
    <span class="md-title">Receipts</span>
  </span>
  <span *ngIf="!searchBox.searchVisible" class="push-left-sm">
    <span *ngIf="(selectable && !selectedRows.length) || !selectable" class="md-title">Receipts</span>
    <span *ngIf="selectedRows.length && selectable" class="md-body-1">0 item(s) selected</span>
  </span>
  <td-search-box #searchBox backIcon="arrow_back" class="push-right-sm" placeholder="Search here" (searchDebounce)="search($event)" flex>
  </td-search-box>
</div>
<md-divider></md-divider>
<td-data-table
  #dataTable
  [data]="filteredData"
  [columns]="columns"
  [selectable]="selectable"
  [clickable]="clickable"
  [multiple]="multiple"
  [sortable]="true"
  [sortBy]="sortBy"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedRows"
  [sortOrder]="sortOrder"
  (sortChange)="sort($event)">
</td-data-table>
<div class="md-padding" *ngIf="!dataTable.hasData" layout="row" layout-align="center center">
  <h3>No results to display.</h3>
</div>
<td-paging-bar #pagingBar [pageSize]="pageSize" [total]="filteredTotal" (change)="page($event)">
  <span hide-xs>Rows per page:</span>
  <md-select [style.width.px]="50" [(ngModel)]="pageSize">
    <md-option *ngFor="let size of [5,10,15,20]" [value]="size">
      {{size}}
    </md-option>
  </md-select>
  {{pagingBar.range}} <span hide-xs>of {{pagingBar.total}}</span>
</td-paging-bar>
```

And lastly my service

```
getReceipts(path: string, token: string): Observable<Boolean>{
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      headers.append('x-access-token', token);
      headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
      let requestoptions = new RequestOptions({
          headers: headers
      });


      let urlPath: string = this.authUrl + path;
      console.log(urlPath);
      return this.http
          .get(urlPath, requestoptions)
          .map((res: Response) => {  
              let test: Array<SpReceiptModel> = res.json();        
              this.spReceiptList = test;
              if(this.spReceiptList.length !== 0){
                  return true;
              }else{
                  return false;
              }
          })
          .catch((err) => this.handleError(err));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your component you miss call filter() function to update de filteredData in your data-table your define your attribute data like this:

> [data]="filteredData"

then in your component need to call

> this.filter()

At the end of this forEach

```
 this.spReceiptsList.forEach((object)=>{
          let paymentDate = new Date(object.paymentDate);
          let year = paymentDate.getFullYear();
          let month = paymentDate.getMonth()+1;
          let dt = paymentDate.getDate();    
          let hours = paymentDate.getHours();
          let minutes = paymentDate.getMinutes();
          let seconds = paymentDate.getSeconds();
          object.paymentDate = dt+'-' + month + '-'+year+' '+hours+':' + minutes + ':'+seconds;
      });
 this.filter();
```

well you miss update that variable, or you can set the variable filteredData instead of call this.filter()

```
   this.filteredData = this.spReceiptsList;
```

Comment: Thanks after that how do I feed the data from the service to data array so it can display to the template that were am having issues at the moment as you can see am using static data for testing only.